# Dropdown open on hover on desktop, but on click on mobile

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I can't find a solution for Bootstrap 4 to have dropdown that open on hover (on desktop) and on click (when on mobile). All the solutions I found are using jQuery - anyone knows how to do it without that lib?

Comment: Why you don't want to use jquery? Bootstrap depends on jquery. You can use vanilla js

Comment: @Sfili_81 Bootstrap5 doesn't depends on jquery anymore ;) `Bootstrap no longer depends on jQuery and we’ve dropped support for Internet Explorer.` see it [here](https://blog.getbootstrap.com/2020/06/16/bootstrap-5-alpha/).

Comment: Because there is no future for jQuery :) And Bootstrap 5 (that I will be moving to soon) proves that so why would I put myself in such place?

Comment: @johannchopin i know but he ask for Bootstrap 4 so i ask ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily achieve this effect by adding the class `.show` to the elements `.dropdown-toggle` and `.dropdown-menu` using pure JavaScript:

```js
const dropdown = document.querySelector('.dropdown');
const dropdownToggle = document.querySelector('.dropdown .dropdown-toggle');
const dropdownMenu = document.querySelector('.dropdown .dropdown-menu');

['mouseover', 'click'].forEach(e => {
  dropdown.addEventListener(e, function() {
    dropdownToggle.classList.add("show");
    dropdownMenu.classList.add("show");
  });
});

dropdown.addEventListener('mouseout', function() {
  dropdownToggle.classList.remove("show");
  dropdownMenu.classList.remove("show");
});
```

```html
<!-- CSS only -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- JS, Popper.js, and jQuery -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Dropdown button
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice one! The only thing with this snippet is on mobile when I click already opened dropdown it's not closing on the next click. How can I solve that?

Comment: @jeand'arme If it's on mobile you can [toggle the class](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_toggle_class.asp) on click event: `myVar.classList.toggle("show");`

Comment: Will implement and let you know later how it went (with accepting answer as well) - thanks!

Comment: It worked! The only thing I couldn't resolve by myself is when I hover on (to open) and then click to close (it closes after second click). If it's something quick - would love to solve this either. If not - I'm already happy with what I achieved with this nice simple snippet :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in a simple way by using CSS like this:

```
@media (min-width: 992px) {
    .dropdown:hover>.dropdown-menu {
        display: block;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap 4 is using jQuery, you can't use the first without the second.

To do this, you can use two diffents event listener (three if you want to close the dropdown after hover) in JavaScript, like :

```
dropdownElement.addEventListener('click', function() {
    . . .
});
dropdownElement.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
    . . .
});
dropdownElement.addEventListener('mouseout', function() {
    . . .
});
```